# Roots of An Equation - Finding Equations in other degrees of roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

(Link: https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/viewer/caie/cambridge-advanced-as-and-a-level-mathematics-9231-2021-may-june-9231s21gtpdf-9231s21ms11pdf-9231s21ms12pdf-9231s21ms13pdf-9231s21ms21pdf-9231s21ms22pdf-9231s21ms23pdf-9231s21ms31pdf-9231s21ms32pdf-9231s21ms33pdf-9231s21ms41pdf-9231s21ms42pdf-9231s21ms43pdf-9231s21qp11pdf)

This is from a paper, so I'll give a summary of the question first.

$x^{4}-2x^{3}-1=0$

has roots $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma , \delta$

a) Find equation with $\alpha^{3} ,\beta^{3} ,\gamma^{3} , \delta^{3}$

*Answer* $y = x^{3}$

Therefore, $y^{4}-8y^{3}-12y^{2} - 6y - 1 = 0$

b) Find the value of  $1/\alpha ^{3}+ 1/\beta ^{3} + 1/\gamma ^{3} + 1/\delta ^{3}$

*Answer* -6

*** c) Find the value of $\alpha ^{4}+ \beta ^{4} + \gamma ^{4} + \delta ^{4}$ ***

Now the mark scheme says
$\alpha ^{4}+ \beta ^{4} + \gamma ^{4} + \delta ^{4} = 2(\alpha ^{3}+\beta ^{3}+\gamma^{3}+\delta ^{3}) + 4$ which is = 20. The mark scheme also says *Uses original equation*

Can someone explain to me how they got this equation for question C? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Uses original equation*" $\;-\;$ The original equation says that $\alpha^4-2\alpha^3-1=0$.  Can you use that?

Comment: Yeah it's probably something along those lines, but I can't quite figure out how to use it. Like where does the 4 come from? And how does x^4 = (a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)?

Comment: That gives $\alpha^4=2\alpha^3+1$. Write the same for $\beta,\gamma,\delta$ and add them up.

Comment: Thanks dxiv, I understood it now, pretty obvious :(

Comment: Glad it helped. It's more obvious *after* you see it for the first time ;-)

Comment: It is perfectly fine, even encouraged, to post a self answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From dxiv)

*Original Equation* $x^4 - 2x^3 - 1 = 0$

Therefore $x^4 = 2x^3 +1 $

Using each of the roots instead of x, we get

$\alpha^4 = 2\alpha^3 +1$

.....

.....

$\delta^4 = 2\delta^3 +1$

Add these all together to get $\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4+\delta^4 = 2(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+\delta^3) + 4$